# How to use a custom framework in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I've searched various websites for a solution to this problem, and haven't found one which actually works for me.

What I have is a custom framework, which shows up as follows in Xcode's `Derived Data` folder:

[image: Framework Folder]

As you can see, it's a `universal` framework. From my understanding, this means, that it can be used for actual *iOS Devices* **and** *Simulator* alike.

In order to generate the `universal` framework, I got the following run script from some tutorial, which I can't recall:

```
#CONFIG=${CONFIGURATION}
CONFIG=Release

# Step 1.
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-universal
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2.
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="$BUILD_ROOT" clean build

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="$BUILD_ROOT" clean build

# Step 3.
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Step 4.
lipo -create -output  "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

---

So now I have `LanguageKit.framework`.
I want to use this framework in a single view application.

How would I go about including the framework in the project?

Answer (score 6):

You have to perform following:

1. Drag your framework into workspace
2. Check "Copy items if needed"
3. Goto project Target > General > Embedded Binaries and click +
   [image]
4. Select *LanguageKit.framework* from under my project
5. Clean and build (success)

Comment: I am getting a issue when I using a object class from some framework like _OBJC_CLASS_$_Person", referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512528/objc-class-person-referenced-from-objc-class-ref-in-viewcontroller-o)